# UICollectionView select and deselect

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView 2 rows 10+ cells.
deselected by default. when I click it becomes selected but when I click again not deselect.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath)


   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)


    let collectionActive: UIImageView = {
        let image=UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "collectionActive"))
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return image
    }()

    let collectionInactive: UIImageView = {
        let image=UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "collectionInactive"))
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return image
    }()


    if cell?.isSelected == true {
        cell?.backgroundView = collectionActive
    }else{
        cell?.backgroundView = collectionInactive
    }

}
```

how fix that problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in viewDidLoad()

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
```

afterword I implemented these methods

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.toggleSelected()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.toggleSelected()
}
```

finally in my class

```
class MyCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    func toggleSelected ()
    {
        if (selected){
            backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }else {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: not working :( 

Could not cast value of type 'VoiceStage.CustomCell' (0x10b4c66b0) to 'VoiceStage.ProfileDetailViewController.MyCell' (0x10b4c6618).
2018-03-15 18:32:31.619053+0300 VoiceStage[2077:177037] Could not cast value of type 'VoiceStage.CustomCell' (0x10b4c66b0) to 'VoiceStage.ProfileDetailViewController.MyCell' (0x10b4c6618).

Comment: and i am use swift 4

Comment: add the 'toggleSelected' function to your 'CustomCell' class, and change the delegate methods to cast to 'as! CustomCell', not 'MyCell'.

Comment: where does the selected come from? When I tried to implement this the class doesn't know what selected is.

Answer (score 4):

**For Swift 5 +**

in viewDidLoad()

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

afterword I implemented these methods

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MovieDetailsDateCollectionViewCell
    cell.toggleSelected()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MovieDetailsDateCollectionViewCell
    cell.toggleSelected()
}
```

In TableView Cell class

```
 class MyCell : UICollectionViewCell {

    func toggleSelected ()
       {
        if (isSelected){
            backgroundColor = .red
           }else {
            backgroundColor = .white
           }
       }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to enable multiple selection and only want one cell to be selected at a time, you can use the following delegate instead:

If the cell is selected then this deselects all cells, otherwise if the cell is not selected, it selects it as normal.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if cell.isSelected {
        collectionView.selectItem(at: nil, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [UICollectionView class doc,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620138-selectedbackgroundview) you can use:

```
var selectedBackgroundView: UIView? { get set }
```

> You can use this view to give the cell a custom appearance when it is selected. When the cell is selected, this view is layered above the backgroundView and behind the contentView.

In your example in the `cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?` function you can set:

```
cell.backgroundView = collectionInactive
cell.selectedBackgroundView = collectionActive
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cell is selected, just set `cell.isSelected = false` in `shouldSelectItemAt` delegate and in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` block. So the state is actually changed to `false` (very) soon after the `shouldSelectItemAt` has been executed.

It may look like a hack but it actually works.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
  if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath), cell.isSelected {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // change the isSelected state on next tick of the ui thread clock
      cell.isSelected = false
      self.collectionView(collectionView, didDeselectItemAt: indexPath)
    }

    return false
  }

  return true
}
```

Please let me know if you find/know any cons to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 14 and newer, you can set the `backgroundConfiguration` property of a cell. Once set, all necessary visual effects for selecting and deselecting works automatically. You can use one of the preconfigured configurations, like this:

```
cell.backgroundConfiguration = .listSidebarCell()
```

…or create a `UIBackgroundConfiguration` object from scratch. You can also change a preconfigured configuration before applying.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibackgroundconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

```
override var isSelected: Bool{
   didSet{
     if self.isSelected
       {
       //This block will be executed whenever the cell’s selection state is set to true (i.e For the selected cell)
       }
       else
       {
      //This block will be executed whenever the cell’s selection state is set to false (i.e For the rest of the cells)
       }
   }
}
```

Add this to your cell

[Source](https://medium.com/hackernoon/uicollectionviewcell-selection-made-easy-41dae148379d)